# Hyperlink target in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm embedding a Google Spreadsheet that contains links (=HYPERLINK(url, [link_label])) in an iframe.
I want to set the link target to the current tab, but it's set to _blank by default.

Is there ANY solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Use  [`.setLinkTarget(linkTarget)`](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference#customsearchcontrol-methods) to set the link target for links embedded in search result. `linkTarget` supplies the target iframe in which to open links.

Here's are the sample linkTarget:

- `LINK_TARGET_BLANK` opens links in a new window (for example, a href=... target=_blank ...>). This is the default.
- `LINK_TARGET_SELF` opens links in the same window and frame (for example, a href=... target=_self ...>).
- `LINK_TARGET_TOP` opens links in the topmost frame (for example, ).
- `LINK_TARGET_PARENT` either opens links in the topmost frame, or replaces the current frame (for example, A href=... target=_parent ...>).
- `anything-else` specifies that links open in the specified frame or window (for example, a href=... target=anything-else ...>).

Comment: Cool!
Sorry, but where do I put this?